# XPath/Scrapy scrape DOCTYPE

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, doctype

Hi there guys and gals,

I'm building a scraper using Scrapy and XPath. What I'm interested in scraping is the DOCTYPE from all of the sites that I traverse and I am having difficulty finding documentation regarding this and I feel as though it should be possible, given that it is a relatively simple request. Any suggestions?

Cheers,

Joey

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from tutorial.items import DanishItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import csv


class DanishSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "dmoz"
  allowed_domains = []
  start_urls = [very long list of websites]

  def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath(???):
      item = DanishItem()
      item['website'] = response
      item['DOCTYPE'] = sel.xpath('????').extract()
      yield item
```

New spider, retrieves DOCTYPE but for some reason will print my response to the specified .json file 15 times as opposed to just once

```
class DanishSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "dmoz"
  allowed_domains = []
  start_urls = ["http://wwww.example.com"]

  def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.selector._root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype:
      el = response.selector._root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype
      item = DanishItem()
      item['website'] = response
      item['doctype'] = el
      yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `scrapy` uses `lxml` as a default selector, you can use the `response.selector` handle to get this info from the `lxml`, like this:

```
response.selector._root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype
```

This should be enough, but if you would another approach, read on.

You should be able to extract the same information by using the `scrapy`'s regex extractor:

```
response.selector.re("<!\s*DOCTYPE\s*(.*?)>")
```

but, unfortunately, this will not work due to the fact that `lxml` has a rather questionable behavior ([a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/659367)?) of dropping the `doctype` info when serialized. This is why you can't get it directly from the `selector.re`.
You can overcome this small obstacle simple enough by utilizing the `re` module directly on the `response.body` text, which is properly serialized:

```
import re
s  = re.search("<!\s*doctype\s*(.*?)>", response.body, re.IGNORECASE)
doctype = s.group(1) if s else ""
```

**Update**:

As for your other question, the reason is the following. The line:

```
response.selector._root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype
```

return a `string`, not a list or similar iterator. Thus, when you iterate through it, you are basically iterating through the letters in that string. If for example, your DOCTYPE is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, there are 15 characters in that string, and that is why your loop is iterated 15 times. You can verify this like:

```
for sel in response.selector._root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype:
    print sel
```

and you should get your DOCTYPE string printed one characted per line.

What you should do is just remove the `for` loop altogether, and just fetch your data without looping. Also, if by `item['website'] = response` you intend to collect the website's URL, you should change this to: `item['website'] = response.url`. So its basically:

```
def parse(self, response):
  doctype = response.selector._root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype
  item = DanishItem()
  item['website'] = response.url
  item['doctype'] = doctype
  yield item
```

Comment: This works great! Only thing that I can't seem to figure out now is why I am getting the response written to my .json file 15 times as opposed to just once, see above edit

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! This works out great :)

Comment: Is there a real need of parsing the Html? Because this should do just fine:
    `In [6]: response.body_as_unicode().split('\n', 1)[0]
    Out[6]: u'<!DOCTYPE html>'`

Comment: You are right @nramirezuy, this is certainly to consider. But this still needs an additional check whether the first line actually is the DOCTYPE, because there doesn't have to bee one.